# Javascript - Split a string based on a character but retain it in the resulting array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

**Input**

```
((Sass and Javascript) or (Python and Scala))
```

**Delimiters** -"(" and ")"

**Output** is an Array with the delimiters present as elements

```
["(","(","Sass and Javascript",")","or","(","Python and Scala",")",")"]
```

The problem that I am facing is this.

```js
var arr = "((Sass and Javascript) or (Python and Scala))".split(/[(|)]/);
console.log(arr);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = arr;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

When I use **split** on the string, I am losing the "(" and ")" characters and since they might occur anywhere in the string, I will need to insert them into the Array manually. Is there a better way to do this in JS?

Comment: have you tried `regex`?

Comment: `"((Sass and Javascript) or (Python and Scala))".match(/[()]|[^()]+/g)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use regex

```
/[()]|[^()]*/g
```

[**Regex Demo and Explanation**](https://regex101.com/r/wT1qX3/1)

1. `[()]`: Matches `(` or `)` exactly once
2. `|`: OR
3. `[^()]`: Negated class, exclude `(` and `)`
4. `*`: Match zero or more of the preceding class
5. `g`: Global match

**Demo**

```js
var str = '((Sass and Javascript) or (Python and Scala))';
var matches = str.match(/[()]|[^()]*/g) || [];
matches.pop(); // Remove the last empty match from array

console.log(matches);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(matches, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks Tushar. That's a neat way to do it.

Comment: @bhargavponnapalli Welcome :) Glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

Just simple

```
var string = '((Sass and Javascript) or (Python and Scala))';
var result = str.match(/[()]|[^()]*/g);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "abcdeabcde";
string = string.replace(/(/gi, ",(,");
string= string.replace(/)/gi, ",),");
var newstring = string.split(",");
return newstring;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var log = function(val){
  console.log(val);
  document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(val , null , ' ') + '</pre>');
  }

var firstStr = '((Sass and Javascript) or (Python and Scala))';
var secondStr = '{>Sass and Javascript< or [Python and Scala]}';


var firstArr = firstStr.match(/[^A-Za-z ]|[A-Za-z ]+/g);
var secondArr = secondStr.match(/[^A-Za-z ]|[A-Za-z ]+/g);

     log(firstArr);
     log(secondArr);
```

```html
<div id ='el'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use capturing parentheses in the split to simplify this a bit. (Note this is apparently not supported by all browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split )

When you use capturing parentheses in a split regex, the captured delimiters are returned in the list along with the 'split' content.

```
"((Sass and Javascript) or (Python and Scala))".split(/\s*([()])\s*/)
```

Output

```
["", "(", "", "(", "Sass and Javascript", ")", "or", "(", "Python and Scala", ")", "", ")", ""]
```

You might need to process it afterwards to exclude zero-length elements.